# Trying to post specific PHP form values to SOAP wsdl with no success

Tags: php, soap

Attemping to post PHP form data from another PHP file to a SOAP wsdl based on if statement of one of the criteria.  I cannot get his to work for the life of me. I am new so I know I make many mistakes.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['submit'] ) ){
$INPUT_STATE=$_GET['INPUT_STATE'];
$SHIP_FROM_STATE = $_GET['SHIP_FROM_STATE'];
$SHIP_FROM_ADDRESS= $_GET['SHIP_FROM_ADDRESS'];
$SHIP_FROM_CITY= $_GET['SHIP_FROM_CITY'];
$SHIP_FROM_ZIP= $_GET['SHIP_FROM_ZIP'];
if ($SHIP_FROM_STATE=='CA');

require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\addemp\Tax\nusoap.php');
$wsdl = 'http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/rates.svc?wsdl';
$server = new SoapClient ($wsdl);
$params= SoapFunction(array(
'StreetAddress'=> $SHIP_FROM_ADDRESS,
'City'=>$SHIP_FROM_CITY,
'ZipCode'=> $SHIP_FROM_ZIP));
$result = $server->call('GetRate', $params);
print_r($result);

}ELSE
```

Comment: what's the actual problem?

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: Form values post to a mysql database as part of form action, but for this instance when certain values passed I want the php file to take values to make a soap call to this wsdl to return tax rates and then write to the database.  I don't have an ability to debug so it has been a series of trial and error to get this to fun.  SOAP is a PITA.  I appreciate any help.